# How to make javascript debounce work in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble using debounce method in react which works perfectly in javascript when we set input field onInput to a function , like , using **setSearchData function** , `<input type='text onInput='setSearchData ()'/>`
but the same debounce logic doesn't work . I don't get any text on my textarea nor do I get any console.log
My debounce logic consists of `setSearchData` ,`searchData2` and `searchData3` functions.
But here I think since I'm using event I can't get any value. I've also tried using

```
document.getElementById('texx).addEventListener('input',setSearchData,false)
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { TextField, Grid, Box, makeStyles, Toolbar, createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider, Container, AppBar, Divider, Card, CardMedia } from '@material-ui/core'
import PrimarySearchAppBar from '../Appbar'
import axios from 'axios';
import Wearcard from './Wearcard';

const useStyles = makeStyles({

})

const Weather = () => {


    const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
    const [city, setCity] = useState([])
    const [addCity, setaddCity] = useState([])

    const fetchLocat = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${search}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)

            console.log(data)
            setCity(data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)

        }
    }
    // debounce method for search hook
    // document.getElementById('texx').addEventListener('input', setSearchData, false)


    **const searchData3 = (event) => {
        setSearch(event.target.value)
        let ds = 1;
        console.log('wow', ds++)
    }
    const searchData2 = (func, delay) => {
        let timer;
        return function () {
            let context = this;
            let argss = arguments;
            clearTimeout(timer)
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                searchData3.apply(context, arguments);
            }, delay)
        }
    }
    const setSearchData = searchData2(searchData3, 1200);**




    useEffect(() => {
        fetchLocat()
    }, [search])

    console.log(this)

    return (
        <div>
            <PrimarySearchAppBar color='secondary' />
            <Toolbar />

            <Container>

                <Divider />

                <br />
                **<TextField label='Enter pin code' id='texx' className='searchhold' value={search} variant='filled' size='medium' type='search' name='cityName'  onInput={setSearchData}>**


                </TextField>
                <br /><br /><br /><br />

                <Grid>
                    <Wearcard />


                </Grid>

            </Container>
        </div >)
}

export default Weather;
```

Comment: Since I made this work by removing value property from <TextField/>  , so will this make my form uncontrolled?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you are using like, This will not work

```
<input type='text onInput='setSearchData ()'/>
```

To Make it work, Update like

```
<input type='text onInput={setSearchData}/>
```

**Clean and reusable approach**

```
const debounce = (func, delay) => {
  let timer;
  return function (...args) {
    let context = this;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => func.apply(context, args), delay);
  };
};

const searchData3 = (event) => {
  setSearch(event.target.value);
  let ds = 1;
  console.log("wow", ds++);
};
const setSearchData = debounce(searchData3, 1200);
```

Comment: Actually I was using onInput='setSearchData()' on using plain js and index.html file where it worked .But in react  I'm using <TextField label='Enter pin code'  value={search}   onInput={setSearchData}> . I also tried your modifications, same result .

Comment: I just  tried removing the value attribute from textfield and for some reason it started working in both my and your code

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the answer above,

1. You may use `lodash`, which done the debounce function for you

```
import delay from "lodash/debounce";

const delay = /* some number */;
const searchData3 = event => debounce(() => {
  setSearch(event.target.value);
}, delay);
```

2. React 18 (still in alpha) now support this natively and much better than `setTimeout`.

```
import { startTransition } from "react"

const searchData3 = event => startTransition(() => {
  setSearch(event.target.value); // this will run in lower priority then other setState
});
```